# Which is faster, using iteration or a simple loop counter?

Tags: c++, optimization, vector, iteration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ STL: Which method of iteration over a STL container is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716762/c-stl-which-method-of-iteration-over-a-stl-container-is-better)
>   [Efficiency of vector index access vs iterator access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506018/efficiency-of-vector-index-access-vs-iterator-access)

Assuming an `std::vector<int>` named `numbers`, which of the following is faster?

```
for (vector<int>::iterator i = numbers.begin(); i != numbers.end(); i++)
  cout << *i;
```

or..

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
  cout << numbers.at(i);
```

Which one is faster? Is there any significant difference?

Comment: Not sure which is faster, but it's almost certainly insignificant.

Comment: cout is going to be the limiting factor here, by FAR. You won't make a benchmarking program that shows any difference in speed if you're printing them all to the terminal.

Comment: I ran a test similar to this on my system and found `at()` to be the slowest method (at does range checking), iterator being faster, and using an index and `[]` to be fastest. It probably depends on your system and compiler though.

Comment: Since `number.size()` returns an unsigned integral type, I would prefer `std::size_t i = 0;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two aren't even comparable. The former loops through each element, while the latter loops through while checking if the current index is valid (with `at()`). Take out the check and ask again:

```
for (/* Not an int! Unsigned type: */ std::size_t i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
    cout << numbers[i];
```

Now they do the same thing. And now the question is a duplicate (#[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716762/c-stl-which-method-of-iteration-over-a-stl-container-is-better) #[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506018/efficiency-of-vector-index-access-vs-iterator-access)). To summarize: it doesn't matter.

Comment: Oh. `size_t` is preferable to `int` or `unsigned int`? I did not know that. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @JonathanLingle size_t usually only matters for avoiding the compiler warning you get for comparing signed int vs. unsigned result of `.size()`. Using int also restricts the size of container you can work with, but usually int's range is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Any difference will be dependent on the hardware and the compiler, so you'd have to measure. I'd expect no significant difference except on exotic hardware with a non-optimizing compiler.

And of course IO is likely to far outweigh the loop overhead.